# How to pass apex:column parameters to div?

Tags: visualforce

Hi my requirment is when i click on lastname open seperate div with record details when i change fields and click on update button record should be update in table. but parameters not passing to div class can any one tell me why code not working ..

This my visualforce page:

```
<apex:page controller="getinsertcontactdetails" showheader="false">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#cls').hide();
$('#alt').click(function(){
   $('#cls').toggle();
});
    });
</script>
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
 <apex:inputtext value="{!query}" id="query" styleclass="input" html-placeholder="search" />
  <apex:commandbutton value="GO" action="{!runQuery}" styleclass="gobut" style="background-color:black;"/>
 <apex:pageblockSection columns="1">
<apex:pageblocktable value="{!contacts}" var="con">
<apex:column headerValue="id" value="{!con.id}" id="targetid"/>
<apex:column headerValue="Name">
 <apex:outputlink value="view"> {!con.firstName} <apex:param name="id" value="{!con.id}"/> </apex:outputlink>
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="LastName" >
 <!--- <a href="#" id="alt" rerender="cls">{!con.lastname}
</a> ---->
<div id="alt">
<apex:commandlink action="{!detail}" value="{!con.lastname}" style="color:black;border-radius:3px;margin-left:150px;font-size:14px;" rerender="cls" >
<apex:param name="doid" value="{!con.id}" assignTo="{!conid}"/>
<apex:param name="cnam" value="{!con.firstname}" assignTo="{!fn}"/>
<apex:param name="clas" value="{!con.lastname}" assignTo="{!ln}"/>
<apex:param name="cami" value="{!con.email}" assignTo="{!em}"/>
</apex:commandlink>
</div>
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Email" value="{!con.email}"/>
</apex:pageblocktable>
</apex:pageblockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
<div id="cls">
<b><apex:outputLabel value="firstname" style="color:red;" styleclass="label"></apex:outputLabel></b><br/>
<apex:inputtext value="{!fn}" id="fs" styleclass="input"/><br/><br/>
<b><apex:outputLabel value="lastname" style="color:red;" styleclass="label"></apex:outputLabel></b><br/>
<apex:inputtext value="{!ln}" id="ls" styleclass="input"/><br/><br/>
<b><apex:outputLabel value="Email" style="color:red;" styleclass="label1"></apex:outputLabel></b><br/>
<apex:inputtext value="{!em}" id="es" styleclass="input"/><br/><br/>
<apex:commandbutton value="Update" action="{!updatecon}"/>
</div>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to try is to change this raw HTML:

```
<div id="cls">
    ...
</div>
```

into the corresponding Apex component:

```
<apex:outputPanel layout="block" id="cls">
    ...
</apex:outputPanel>
```

as re-rendering is an Apex component mechanism.